# How to push data from one client to another client using WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

As the title.
Can somebody give me an simple example how to push and get data between 2 clients through WCF service?
I've tried using Polling Duplex but doesn't work.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean sending the data to  the other client through server. Correct?

Comment: Correct.
Thats what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

WCF has a rather nice **peer-to-peer networking mode** that you might find useful.  As MSDN says:

> *Peer Channel is a multiparty, peer-to-peer (P2P) communication technology in Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). It provides a secure and scalable message-based P2P communication channel for application developers. One common example of a multiparty application that can benefit from Peer Channel is a collaborative application, such as chat, where a group of people chat with one another in a peer-to-peer manner without servers. Peer Channel enables P2P collaboration, content distribution, load balancing, and distributed processing for both consumer and enterprise scenarios -* [More...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733761(v=vs.110).aspx)

A nice walk-through article can be found here:

- [A Peer-To-Peer Work Processing App With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882514.aspx)